# HIbernate suddenly started to validate JPA annotations

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity that maps a database table in my code, this entity has the following attribute:

```
@Column(name = "CARD_TYPE", length = 255,nullable = false)
private String cardType;
```

When this entity was created the column in the database had this field defined as non nullable, but due to a change in the business logic it is no longer the case. The field in the database was updated to allow this field to be null but the entity in the java code was not. Now, when testing in several environments with different instances of the same database we had no problems, but as of yesterday, after this code had been running for about a week without issues, we are getting this message over and over

```
error javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: entity.cardType | Cause: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: entity.cardType
```

This exception if from Hibernate which means that it never even tries to reach the database. Is my understanding that @Column annotation is only used when creating the database schemas from code and not used for validation. We have another instance of the same code in another server running against the same database and it doesn't show the error.

Comment: It doesn't show the error because you're not trying to store a null cardType inside a clumn that is marked as non nullable. See check_nullability in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_bean_validation_options

Comment: at the point where the error pops up the cardType is always null in both instances. One gives an error, the other does not